# C# - Web Site - SQL Select Statement

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sqldatareader

I want to use a select statement to find if there is a record that already exists. I've put the code below but it throws an error at the dReader = comm.ExecuteReader(); and i'm unsure why. Any help?

```
    string connString = "Data Source=KIMMY-MSI\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";

    SqlDataReader dReader;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.Connection = conn;

    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID == " + txtID.Text;
    comm.Connection.Open();

    dReader = comm.ExecuteReader();

    if (dReader.HasRows == true)
    {
        Response.Write("Exists");
    }
```

The error:

```
Invalid Column Name (whatever I input)
```

It seems to be looking for a column named what I input rather than looking for the actual data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `==` to `=`. That is invalid SQL as it is.

Also if txtID.Text is non-numeric then it needs to be in single quotes. You should not be constructing your SQL like this, instead use a parameter:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID", txtID.Text);
```

#### More Info

[C# using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

[SQL reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_quickref.asp)

[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (why you should parameterize your queries)

Comment: When changing it to = it says :    Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = ?

Comment: And : Property or indexer 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.HasRows' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: You're changing that in the wrong spot - check my answer here for the two lines you need to edit. (Leave your `if` statement as is.)

Comment: Ok, well thats sorted, but it is still looking for a Column Named what I input, rather than looking for the data I input.

Comment: You probably didn't put the value in single quotes. Just copy and paste my two lines in place of your one `comm.CommandText = ...` line.

Comment: Thanks. The code was exactly the same as yours - i've checked it over and over! - but for some reason when I copied it from here and put it in place of mine it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped. I'm going to add some links for your reference.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your command has an issue:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID == 1
```

In SQL you don't need to use the == operator to ensure something is equal to another.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 1
```

In addition, you might want to read up about SQL Injection, the way you are binding the value is directly from a textbox value. This has a huge security hole which could lead to arbitrary sql command execution.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID == " + txtID.Text;
```

To this line:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @id";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", int.Parse(txtID.Text));
```

Assuming that your customer id is int on the database.

Answer (score 1):

The equals operator in SQL is just a single `=`.

Also, you really shouldn't be concatenating SQL queries like that, you are just opening yourself up to [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So change it to be like this:

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerId";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", txtID.Text);
```

See [Stop SQL Injection Attacks Before They Stop You](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163917.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

You are using invalid SQL. You name to change "==" to "=".

You should also consider wrapping your `IDisposable` objects in `using` statements so that unmanaged objects are properly disposed of and connections are properly closed.

Finally, think about using parameters in your SQL, instead of concatenating strings, to avoid SQL injection attacks:

```
string connString = @"Data Source=KIMMY-MSI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    comm.Connection.Open();
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", txtID.Text);
    using (SqlDataReader dReader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dReader.HasRows == true)
        {
            Response.Write("Exists");
        }   
    }
}
```