# Need a Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to replace text in string:

```
string s="Insert into VERSION (ENTRYID,APPVERSION,PLATFORMVERSION,TIMESTAMPED,USERNAME,SQLSCRIPTNAME,COMMENTS)VALUES(SWS_Version_ID."NEXTVAL",'[3.02.01P20]','[4.1.38orcl]',sysdate,null,null,null);";
```

I need to replace 3.02.01P20 in square brackets to NEW_VERSION.
There can be other version except 3.02.01P20 but in the line we can see that the first opening square bracket follows the version.

Also let me know what changes do I have to make if it(3.02.01P20) follows, say 3 opening square bracket ([) so that I wont have to write a separate question for each one.

Comment: What have you tried? You might want to look at [a tool like Expresso to help you build and debug your regular expressions](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: You should use Parameter binding instead of setting values by replacing variables in SQL, It's much safer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943178/724944

Comment: @GregB Actually I am a novice in this and dont even know where to start. I will download and play with the tool. Meanwhile can you please help me out ?

Comment: @surfen Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion about SQL but my question was about Regex only, I am not executing this sql script anywhere. My task is just to create code that will replace as explained by me.

Comment: @AkshayJ Then you should look for some [tutorials on regex](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.net+regex+tutorial&aq=0&oq=.net+regex+tu&sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Tester
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "Insert into VERSION " + 
            "(ENTRYID,APPVERSION,PLATFORMVERSION,TIMESTAMPED,USERNAME,SQLSCRIPTNAME,COMMENTS)" +
            "VALUES(SWS_Version_ID.\"NEXTVAL\",'[3.02.01P20]','[4.1.38orcl]',sysdate,null,null,null);";
        Match m = (new Regex("^(.*)(\\[.*?\\])(.*?)(\\[.*?\\])(.*)$")).Match(s);
        //Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
        string[] parts = {
                m.Groups[1].Value,
                m.Groups[2].Value, //[3.02.01P20]
                m.Groups[3].Value, //','
                m.Groups[4].Value, //[4.1.38orcl]
                m.Groups[5].Value //tail
            };
        parts[1] = "[NEW_VERSION]";
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",parts));
    }
}
```

You mean like this?

Comment: @Akshay You mean this answer is not good enough? Which part can be improved?

Comment: answer was more than correct, its just that the code scared me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(s, @"(.*'\[)(.*)(\]'.*)('\[.*)", "$1" + newVer + "$3$4");
```